# Is a 6 hour layover at Munich enough to travel to Connollystraße 21 & be back?

Tags: layovers, munich

Travelling from Delhi to NY via Munich where I have a layover of 6 hours. How long does it take to exit airport to Munich city considering that immigration would stamp my entry ?

Can I travel to Connollystraße by S-Bahn and be back to catch my connecting flight to NY ?

Comment: Which airline are you flying with?

Comment: While 6 hours sounds like a long time, when you strip out the time to clear Immigration, get to your chosen city area, return to the airport and clear security, you’re actually left with not very much (1.5 hours, per the answer from chx). All it would take would be an unforeseen delay or some kind of incident and you could be struggling to get back in time. If you enjoy stress, go for it. If you’re doing it to meet up with friends rather than sightsee, why not get them to come meet you at the airport.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you! Am gonna up-vote all of your answers!
So people here guessed it right .
Flight is LHR 763 Del Munich landing at terminal 2
At 0545
Then connecting flight is LHR410 to NY from terminal 2 at 1215 . What I hear is that there is a positive chance to go out and be back. I have applied a Schengen Visa. So just thinking I can try go visit and come back..

Answer (score 4):

As we have discussed here before, Munich is an extraordinarily efficient airport. Even when things are really bad I wouldn't expect immigration (you need a Schengen visa to go to Munich btw) to take more than 30 minutes, typically less than ten. So by all means you will be out in less than an hour, with a little luck it can be as little as 30 minutes (I presume your luggage is through checked). It's an hour to Connollystraße by S1 and U3, another to get back. I would plan to get back to the airport 90 minutes before to make it safe. I would expect you will have about 1.5 hours at Connollystraße.

Edit: to roll some of the comments into the answer, yes, the old Terminal 1 is not so great but I readily presumed OP is flying Delhi-Munich direct which means they are flying on Lufthansa because at this time the only direct flight between the two is LH763 (arriving 5:25AM) and so they will use Terminal 2. (Even if Air India starts a flight, this will still be true because all *A airlines except TK are in T2). However, when I look at the Munich-New York flights -- there are not many -- all of them are from Terminal 2: United at 9:30AM, Lufthansa at 12:25PM and 4:05PM. Either OP has seven hours or one of the legs is not direct.

Comment: That feels a little optimistic. The S1 goes only  every 20 minutes and the S8 takes significantly longer, so I'd budget and extra 15 minutes each way to actually catch the Subway . 90 minutes is also a little tight for US bound flights since there are often extra security and control measures.  I agree, that it's doable, but depending on your risk tolerance there isn't a whole lot of time at the destination

Comment: This answer could be utterly confusing unless you know which airline OP is flying with. Terminal 2 in Munich is extraordinarily efficient, but terminal 1 surely isn't. It is not uncommon that I queue up for 45 or even 60 minutes just to get through security. I've never flown out of Schengen from terminal 1, but recently a friend of mine missed his flight to Dublin after spending more than an hour waiting for passport control.

Comment: The OP does have the advantage though that they can see what time it is after clearing immigration (they will, of course, need a visa or a passport that permits visa-free entry to the Schengen area for any of this to matter). If immigration takes a long time, they can consider if a very short visit at Connollystraße 21 is worthwhile or if they want to abandon the plan and stay at the airport.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo If OP is flying DEL-MUC direct, that's LH763 which lands at Terminal 2. Easy :)